# module representation and tensor product

Tags: modules, tensor-products

I am new to tensor product and I am reading about module representations, a homomorphism $M\xrightarrow{\theta}\text{Hom}(V,W)$ where $M,V$ and $W$ are $R$-modules. However, I wanted to understand  this module representation $\theta_n:M\otimes R/I^n\xrightarrow{}\text{Hom}(V\otimes R/I^n,W\otimes R/I^n)$ where R is a ring with one maximal ideal $I$. Let $m\in M$ and $a\in R/I^n$. The map $\theta_n$ is given by $(m\otimes a)\theta_n=m\theta\otimes a$.

I just need to understand what is happening in words

Comment: Hi! Where did you read this?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

Start with three $R$-modules $M,N$ and $O$, and an $R$-linear map
$$
\theta \colon M \to \text{Hom}(N,O).
$$
Given an $R$-algebra $S$, for each $s \in S$ consider the $R$-linear map $\rho_s \colon S \to S$ defined by $\rho_s(x)=xs$.
Now, since for each $m \in M$ we have the $R$-linear map $\theta(m) \colon N \to O$, for every pair $(m,s) \in M \times S$ we have the $R$-linear map
$$
\theta(m) \otimes \rho_s \colon N \otimes S \to O \otimes S.
$$
So, we have a function $M \times S \to \text{Hom}(N \otimes S, O \otimes S)$, which is easily shown to be $R$-bilinear. By the universal property of the tensor product, this gives us the desired $R$-linear map
$$
\theta^S \colon M \otimes S \to \text{Hom}(N \otimes S, O \otimes S),
$$
that is, the one such that, if $(m,s) \in M \times S$,
$$
\theta^S(m \otimes s) = \theta(m) \otimes \rho_s.
$$